Deadlock when running SELECT x WHERE y FOR UPDATE
I'm using MySQL version 8.3.0 from a Docker image, with the default configuration.
I simplified my use-case to a table with just 2 columns. What I want to achieve is to block simultaneous transactions from inserting records for the same "group" (in this case to the same product_sku), but to allow them to insert for other "groups".
By going through the docs at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html I understood that by running SELECT x FROM y WHERE z FOR UPDATE I would only lock rows satisfying condition z, without locking all the other ones. However this doesn't seem to be the case.
My table:
CREATE TABLE `example` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_sku` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `example_product_sku_IDX` (`product_sku`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

I run two MySQL sessions - AA and BB:
AA> BEGIN;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)

AA> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name='autocommit';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| autocommit    | OFF   |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

BB> BEGIN;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)

BB> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name='autocommit';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| autocommit    | OFF   |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

AA> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM example WHERE product_sku = 'abc' FOR UPDATE;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

BB> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM example WHERE product_sku = 'def' FOR UPDATE;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

AA> INSERT INTO example (product_sku) VALUES ('abc');
(this query hangs up...)

BB> INSERT INTO example (product_sku) VALUES ('def');
ERROR 1213 (40001): Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction

(at this point query from AA executes):
Query OK, 1 row affected (4,02 sec)

From my understanding the two locks should be independent, as they should lock different range of rows. However they are not.
I tried the below changes, without success:

removing the example_product_sku_IDX index
changing SELECT COUNT(*) to SELECT *

I'm trying to understand whether I'm doing something wrong or MySQL has a bug. I found a similar question on MySQL board, but it's not very helpful in terms of explaining the problem - https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=96748

why use For Update, when you don't need it , you have to look at the locks that your first select produces.

In case of two connections trying to insert records to the same "group", I need the second one to wait until the first one is committed. However the behaviour I can see is in the example above is not what I would expect. I tested FOR SHARE to check the difference, but the outcome is exactly the same.

two connection have a "table cache" where they get their data, a lock can happen, but you will normally end the transaction, what you at the moment are not doinging. as rule keeo your transactions as short as it can be and don't lock a row without need.

Thank you for your input, but I'm afraid you miss the point. The question was not about ending transaction or keeping them as short as possible. The question is why it creates a deadlock, when it is supposed to lock two independent sets of records. Please let me know if I can do something to improve my question if it's not clear enough.

After some research I think I can answer my own question.
There are 2 things related to the question above.
First - one needs to set a proper transaction isolation level, as described here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.3/en/set-transaction.html
In this case, the queries should be as follows:
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;

BEGIN;

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM example WHERE product_sku = 'abc' FOR UPDATE;
INSERT INTO example (product_sku) VALUES ('abc');

COMMIT;

Second - in the example above, MySQL won't create any lock if the SELECT x FROM y FOR UPDATE returns empty result. There must be at least one record satisfying the query conditions. So in case of an empty table, when multiple concurrent clients try to insert a row into the same "group", MySQL won't block them if one uses FOR UPDATE type of locking mechanism.
